# Figures on the number of LaTeX users

Tags: statistics

I am looking for figures on the number of academics using Tex or LaTeX.

> How may people use LaTeX?

LaTeX is a computer language used to produce pdfs and make books. It is popular across STEM fields.

I am also interested in related figures that people can find or know about. For example:

- What percentage of textbooks are made using LaTeX?
- What percentage of Springer books are made using LaTeX?
- What percentage of mathematicians (physicists, chemists, biologists, engineers, computer scientists, etc.) use LaTeX?

_

I'm confused about the close-votes. It seems this was the place to put the question, because of what it said in the description of what questions are handled here:

"If you have a question about ...

Formats like LaTeX, ConTeXt and plain TeX
Engines like pdfTeX, LuaTeX and XeTeX
Distributions like TeX Live, MiKTeX, and MacTeX
Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc.
... then you're in the right place to ask your question!"

My question is indeed about these things and amenable to an answer using statistics. Which sorts of questions about usage statistics for these formats are right for a different place?